# Why Source.fromIterator expects a Function0[Iterator[T]] as a parameter instead of Iterator[T]?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

Based on: [source code](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/aa8c253d141a96b65ac19f781106fa82d457c2c2/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.scala#L197-L211)

I don't get why the parameter of `Source.fromIterator` is `Function0[Iterator[T]]` instead of `Iterator[T]`.

Is there a pratical reason for this? Could we change the signature to `def fromIterator(iterator: => Iterator[T])` instead ? (to avoid doing `Source.fromIterator( () => myIterator)` )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#fromIterator):

> The iterator will be created anew for each materialization, which is
>   the reason the method takes a function rather than an iterator
>   directly.

Stream stages are supposed to be re-usable so you can materialize them more than one. A given iterator, however, can (often) be consumed one time only. If `fromIterator` created a Source that referred to an existing iterator (whether passed by name or reference) a second attempt to materialize it could fail because the underlying iterator would be exhausted.

To get around this, the source needs to be able to instantiate a new iterator, so `fromIterator` allows you to supply the necessary logic to do this as a supplier function.

Here's an example of something we don't want to happen:

```
implicit val system = akka.actor.ActorSystem.create("test")
implicit val mat = akka.stream.ActorMaterializer(system)

val iter = Iterator.range(0, 2)
// pretend we pass the iterator directly...
val src = Source.fromIterator(() => iter)

Await.result(src.runForEach(println), 2.seconds)
// 0
// 1
// res0: akka.Done = Done

Await.result(src.runForEach(println), 2.seconds)
// res1: akka.Done = Done
// No results???
```

That's bad because the Source `src` is not re-usable since it doesn't give the same output on subsequent runs. However if we create the iterator lazily it works:

```
val iterFunc = () => Iterator.range(0, 2)
val src = Source.fromIterator(iterFunc)

Await.result(src.runForEach(println), 2.seconds)
// 0
// 1
// res0: akka.Done = Done

Await.result(src.runForEach(println), 2.seconds)
// 0
// 1
// res1: akka.Done = Done
```